# Bash echo newline to file unless part of string

Tags: bash, sed, newline

I want to concat two files to a third file, but preserve newline. For that, I use

```
FILE1=$(cat /path/file1)
FILE2=$(cat /path/file2)
FILE3="$FILE1 \n $FILE2"
echo -e $FILE3 > /path/to/file
```

However, one of the files, I have a `sed` operation that contains the string `\\n`. I do not want this specific `\n` character to be constituted as a newline when I create the third file.

What can I do?

Comment: How is `echo -e` doing concat of 2 files?

Comment: assuming my `$VAR` is the concat of 2 files already

Comment: How are you setting the contents of `$VAR`? If you are reading from a file directly then it doesn't contain `\n` it contain *literal* newlines and you don't need `-e` at all. (You also shouldn't use `echo -e` as it is underspecified and not reliably portable.) That being said you also need to quote `"$VAR"` if you expect whitespace in its contents to be preserved at all.

Comment: Unless you are doing something else with the contents of `$FILE1` and `$FILE2` this is a very inefficient way to do this. Also if you use `$'\n'` instead of `"\n"` you get a literal newline in `$FILE3` and can avoid using `echo -e`.

Comment: @EtanReisner that was a perfect answer for my use case! Yes I am doing other stuff with the files once they are read. If you post this, I can vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're slurping the file contents into variables at all. What's wrong with

```
cat /path/file1 /path/file2 > /path/to/file
```

If you need the FILE1 and FILE2 vars for other purposes, avoid FILE3

```
echo "$FILE1
$FILE2" > /path/to/file
```

or

```
printf "%s\n" "$FILE1" "$FILE2" > /path/to/file
```

or

```
cat <<END_CONCAT > /path/to/file
$FILE1
$FILE2
END_CONCAT
```

Comment: Obviously this is a simplified question to get straight to my core problem. I need to manipulate those files before appending them to a file. Hence, I need to save them to the variable, do my processing, then append.

Comment: The bottom 2/3 of my answer applies. The "\n" and "echo -e" are causing problems, so avoid them.